# Sort a list of list using two values from each list

Tags: python

How can I sort this list of list using the first and second number in each list `[210, 250, 345]`. I want to consider the first values first.

```
my_list  =   [[[([210, 250, 345], 'CERTIFICATE'), ([366, 251, 390], 'OF'), ([397, 252, 551], 'REGISTRATION')], 
               [([1076, 247, 1228], 'SERTIFIKAAT'), ([1234, 248, 1283], 'VAN'), ([1285, 248, 1422], 'REGISTRASIE')],
               [([210, 278, 236], 'IN'), ([237, 277, 330], 'RESPECT'), ([351, 277, 376], 'OF'), ([375, 277, 455], 'MOTOR'),([463, 275, 551], 'VEHICLE')], 
               [([1039, 276, 1091], 'TEN'), ([1093, 276, 1190], 'OPSIGTE'),([1195, 276, 1246], 'VAN'), ([1257, 276, 1448], 'MOTORVOERTUIG')], 
               [([209, 306, 297], '(National'), ([306, 306, 355], 'Road'), ([368, 308, 430], 'Traffic'), ([437, 305, 480], 'Act,'), ([491, 304, 554], '1996)')], 
               [([770, 293, 787], 'IKE'), ([788, 306, 796], 'E')], 
               [([1068, 303, 1174], '(Nasionale'), ([1181, 304, 1372], 'Padverkeerswet,'), ([1374, 304, 1424], '1996)')]]
              ]
```

I've tried:

```
new_content = []

for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
    chunk = sorted(my_list[i], key=lambda x:(x[0][0], x[0][1]))
    new_content.append(chunk)
```

And:

```
for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
    chunk = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x:(x[i][0][0], x[i][0][1]))
    new_content.append(chunk)
```

And:

```
for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
    chunk = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x:(x[i][0][0], x[i+1][0][1]))
    new_content.append(chunk)
```

Desire result:

```
new_list = [[([210, 250, 345], 'CERTIFICATE'), ([366, 251, 390], 'OF'), ([397, 252, 551], 'REGISTRATION')],
            [([210, 278, 236], 'IN'), ([237, 277, 330], 'RESPECT'), ([351, 277, 376], 'OF'), ([375, 277, 455], 'MOTOR'), ([463, 275, 551], 'VEHICLE')],
            [([209, 306, 297], '(National'), ([306, 306, 355], 'Road'), ([368, 308, 430], 'Traffic'), ([437, 305, 480], 'Act,'), ([491, 304, 554], '1996)')],
            [([770, 293, 787], 'IKE'), ([788, 306, 796], 'E')],
            [([1076, 247, 1228], 'SERTIFIKAAT'), ([1234, 248, 1283], 'VAN'), ([1285, 248, 1422], 'REGISTRASIE')]
            [([1039, 276, 1091], 'TEN'), ([1093, 276, 1190], 'OPSIGTE'), ([1195, 276, 1246], 'VAN'), ([1257, 276, 1448], 'MOTORVOERTUIG')],
            [([1068, 303, 1174], '(Nasionale'), ([1181, 304, 1372], 'Padverkeerswet,'), ([1374, 304, 1424], '1996)')],
            [([1076, 247, 1228], 'SERTIFIKAAT'), ([1234, 248, 1283], 'VAN'), ([1285, 248, 1422], 'REGISTRASIE')]]
```

Comment: why 209 is after 210? And 1076 before 1039 and 1068?

Comment: Your original list has 3 levels of nesting, but your result only has 2 levels.

Comment: This is how the Google  API output the response.

Comment: @buran, he takes the first two marks into consideration.

Comment: @ Barmar please you can ignore the level of nesting, what I really want is the ordering

Comment: @Mr. Chip, that doesn't explain how 210 comes before 209, right?

Comment: @  buran, The first values are the starting position of the words and the second values are the bottom position. so 210 and 209 are starting position of the words

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you want this ordering. Why is `[210, 250]` before `[209, 306]`

Comment: imagine this as a plane, the words are arranged in the following order without the vertices:

`CERTIFICATE OF REGISTRATION                  SERTIFIKAAT VAN REGISTRASIE` 
  
`IN RESPECT OF MOTOR VEHICLE                 TEN OPSIGTE 'VAN MOTORVOERTUIG`
..... and so on.....
so I want to get the ones at the left before the ones at the right. And for the `210` before `209` this is how the words appear in a document with the starting position

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt was close, but you didn't notice that there's an extra level of list wrapped around everything. So you need to loop over `my_list[0]`.

There's also no need to use `enumerate()`. You don't need the indexes, just the list elements. And you can use a list comprehension to collect the results into a list.

```
new_content = [sorted(l, key=lambda x:(x[0][0], x[0][1])) for l in my_list[0]]
new_content.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0][0][0], x[0][0][1]))
```

Result:

```
new_list = [[([209, 306, 297], '(National'), ([306, 306, 355], 'Road'), ([368, 308, 430], 'Traffic'), ([437, 305, 480], 'Act,'), ([491, 304, 554], '1996)')],
            [([210, 250, 345], 'CERTIFICATE'), ([366, 251, 390], 'OF'), ([397, 252, 551], 'REGISTRATION')],
            [([210, 278, 236], 'IN'), ([237, 277, 330], 'RESPECT'), ([351, 277, 376], 'OF'), ([375, 277, 455], 'MOTOR'), ([463, 275, 551], 'VEHICLE')],
            [([770, 293, 787], 'IKE'), ([788, 306, 796], 'E')],
            [([1039, 276, 1091], 'TEN'), ([1093, 276, 1190], 'OPSIGTE'), ([1195, 276, 1246], 'VAN'), ([1257, 276, 1448], 'MOTORVOERTUIG')],
            [([1068, 303, 1174], '(Nasionale'), ([1181, 304, 1372], 'Padverkeerswet,'), ([1374, 304, 1424], '1996)')],
            [([1076, 247, 1228], 'SERTIFIKAAT'), ([1234, 248, 1283], 'VAN'), ([1285, 248, 1422], 'REGISTRASIE')]]
```

Comment: @ Barmar this outputs the list in the same ordering as the initial.

Comment: All the initial lists are already sorted.

Comment: It looks like you also want to sort the list of lists. What's the key for that?

Comment: no not really  @ Barmar, have a closer look at both the initial list and the desired result

Comment: I thought you just wanted to sort the innermost lists, not the containing list. I've updated the answer to show how to sort both levels.

Comment: The output is close. Is there a way you can consider the second values as well to get the desired result I wrote above

Comment: I'm considering the first and second values. In the first row, the first value is 209, the second value is 306.

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. Why is `[1076, 247, 1228]` before `[1039, 276, 1091]`?

Comment: I think that I can get the desired output by considering the current values and next values simultaneously.  `210, 250` and `1076, 247` and so on. considering the first and second values. But I don't know how to go about it

Comment: If you can't explain it clearly, you can't code it.

Comment: The initial list is a list of  two column document extracted accordingly(column by column). each inner list is a column. How do I get the first column first and the the second column?. using the numbers associated with the first word in the column

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what you mean.

Comment: It looks like what you have is two documents, one in English and the other in Afrikaans. I guess those are the two colums in the original document. But I still don't understand how that affects ordering within each column.

Comment: I am using google cloud vision to extract the contents of the document. The document has two columns. first column is English and the second column is Afrikaans( translation of the English). That is the English is at the left and Afrikaans is at right .
The ordering  `[210, 250]` before `[209, 306]` means that the content with `[209, 306]` at the starting position has either a white space or a tab before the text. but the content with `[210, 250]` comes before it while reading the document. that is why I am also checking the second value `250` and  `306` which is the bottom line position

Comment: OK, but how is the code supposed to know that `[210, 250]` should come before `[209, 306]`? What is the mathematical logic in your ordering?

Comment: The logic is to check if the` first value of the first item`  `209 for example`  is greater than the `first value of the  next item` `210 for example`.  and at the same time check if the` second value of the first item`  `306 for example`  is greater than the `second value of the  next item` `250for example`. and then sort.  it might look something like this `chunk = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x:(x[i][0][0], x[i+1][0][0], x[i][0][1], x[i+1][0][1]))` or a bubble sort

Comment: Python sorting doesn't let you customize how the comparisons are done. You can just specify the keys that are compared, it uses the built-in `<` operator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we extract the list, since the first nesting level is unused here

`my_list = my_list[0]`

Then we could sort each element (each element is a list of tuple), by getting:

1. The first element that is a tuple(list, str)
2. The first element of the tuple  that is a list
3. The fist element of the nested list (at 2.)

`sorted(my_list, key = lambda x: x[0][0][0])`

Answer (score 0):

I think whether @Bruno would like to sort all the included lists together, or just each included list individually (which I think this is what he is looking for according to its desire result since the nested lists are sorted individually not all togehter), the concept and approach provided by @barmar is the same (just by doing some minor changes you can get what you are looking for)

==============================

I didn't know about sorted(), so I come up with this approach (which is not as easy as the sorted() solution) You can convert the first and second numbers (in each tuple) to string. Then, make sure the first numbers have the same length (if not, extend them by adding 0 before them). Do the same thing for second numbers. Then, join the numbers (that are in string format) together and convert it back to integer. Now, you have only one number based on which you can do sorting!

```
def sort_first_two(my_list = my_list[0][0]):
    first_val = []
    second_val = []

    for item in my_list:
        first_val.append(str(item[0][0]))
        second_val.append((str(item[0][1])))

    max_len_first = max([len(val) for val in first_val])
    max_len_second = max([len(val) for val in second_val])

    first_val_extended = [('0'*(max_len_first-len(val))+val) for val in first_val]
    second_val_extended = [('0'*(max_len_second-len(val))+val) for val in second_val]


    combined_val = [int(a+b) for a,b in zip(first_val_extended,second_val_extended)]

    return combined_val


print(sort_first_two(my_list[0][0]))
```

This gives you the combination of first and second numbers, and then you can just sort them.

Comment: What will be your output? I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "([210, 250, 345], 'CERTIFICATE')([366, 251, 390], 'OF')"`

Comment: Thanks. I just corrected the input of my function. (There were nested lists and I got confused).

Comment: Could you please copy the whole code and run it? (my_list is the input provided in the question, with three opening brackets: [[[ (....

Comment: You can check out the result of combining numbers of another inner list. For instance, feed a new input to the function and print it. For example: print(sort_first_two(my_list[0][2]))

Comment: But, again, the solution `new_content = [sorted(l, key=lambda x:(x[0][0], x[0][1])) for l in my_list[0]]` provided by @Barmar is easier.